# Cannot convert int to String

Tags: android

This doesn't work:

```
int number = 1;
String numberstring = IntToString(number);
```

I get "The method IntToString(int) is undefined for the type (myclassname)"

I must be tired here. What the heck am I forgetting?

Comment: Is there `IntToString method` in your class file - `myclassname`? Is the  arguement types are matching?

Comment: `String.valueof(number)`

Comment: @kakemonsteret remember to mark an answer as correct as it motivates other users to help you in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either:

```
 String numberstring = number.toString();
```

or

```
String numberstring = Integer.toString(number)
```

or (as a tricky thing sometimes I do this)

```
String numberstring = 1 + "";
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
int number = 1;
String numberstring = Integer.toString(number);
```

Comment: Thanks - both String.valueOf() and Integer.toString() worked.

Answer (score 2):

Why not this :

```
int number = 1;
String numberstring = number+"";
```

Also make sure that :

Is there `IntToString` method in your class file - `myclassname`? Is the arguement types are matching?

Answer (score 2):

These ones are the ones that seems to work "out of the box", without importing any special classes:

```
String numberstring = String.valueOf(number);
String numberstring = Integer.toString(number);
String numberstring = number + "";
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this with very little code would be like this:

```
int number = 1;
String numberstring = number + "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting this -

```
int numb = 1;
String val = String.valueOf(numb);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number=1;
String S = String.valueOf(number);
```

try this code... works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, int to String is simple as

```
String numberstring = String.valueOf(number);
```

This applies to Android too.